# Windows 10 Upgrade lost files in C:\PHPPOS

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

When upgrading to windows 10 from windows 8.1 the folder C:\PHPPOS was removed and replaced with the version it had on March. I am trying to downgrade back to windows 8.1 but what would cause this to be restored to such an old date? I lost all my data :(

This folder held a mysql database. This happened to one of my users and am trying to help them. What could they have done to cause this? They said they hit enter on there computer and all of a sudden it was doing a windows 10 upgrade.

Did a restore back to windows 8.1 and it worked and had the data back as before. Why would windows 10 do this? What could be the reason

Comment: Leaving stuff in the root directory is dangerous for a ton of reasons.  But there is no reason that would have happened which tells me, the user, is mistaken about something.  Windows wouldn't just randomly restore a file from March.

Comment: Is there any way they could have done that in windows without realizing it? Like a restore point?

Comment: UPDATE: We did a downgrade back to windows 8 and all the data is back...Something odd is going on.

Comment: Could you just rephrase your question in its entirety.  We don't need "update" notices it clearly indicates the question has been modified already.

Comment: I have removed the edit. We are trying to upgrade again as I watch it to see if we notice anything odd that happens.

Comment: Chris, on restore points, no, they're only for system files. All in all it's hard to imagine this was Windows putting an old folder there and then putting the new one back. Methinks your user is not telling you the whole story. Anyway... best back up the folder now, while you have the chance.

Comment: Well we reverted back to Windows 8.1 and did a backup. We are trying the upgrade again while I supervise him.

Comment: What could explain what happened? Everytime I think about it makes no sense. When we reverted back to windows 8.1 we didn't change any files and it magically worked as before. (The C:\PHPPOS folder was restored and worked)

Comment: I tried updating for 8.1 --> 10 on my machine and did NOT have the issue the user described. What possible thing could the user have done to do this?

Comment: As usual user had an error. Had 2 copies of software....one on desktop one on C:\